# Why non type template parameters that are references need const?

Tags: c++, c++23, non-type-template-parameter

I am familiar with how const behaves for "runtime" code and it makes perfect sense, but since "everything done during compilation is const" (obviously this is not my interpretation, not standard wording) I wonder why C++ cares about if the reference is const or not.

In particular this example does not compile when const is removed:

```
struct Country {
    std::string_view name;
};

template<const /* <-- required */ Country& country>
struct S{
    void print() {
        fmt::print("{}\n", country.name);
    }
};

static constexpr Country sg{.name="Singapore"};
int main() {
    
    S<sg> sg_printer;  
    sg_printer.print();    
}
```

error for gcc is something like:

> error: binding reference of type 'Country&' to 'const Country' discards qualifiers

My only guess that nobody thought about this or that this was done to be same as for "normal" code so that it is consistent.

Comment: you cannot bind a non-const reference to a const object. Why should this be different here?

Comment: if you remove both `const` it compiles as expected https://godbolt.org/z/b85rh1vvo

Comment: "everything done during compilation is const" not entirely sure what you mean with that, but I suppose this is the origin of your confusion. For example within a `constexpr` function, that can be evaluated at compile time, a local variable can be `const` or not `const`, and then either `x = 3;` compiles or not. Not everything during compilation is const

Comment: Also note that `S<const_cast<Country&>(sg)>` will work with the non-const reference NTTP

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number because every template argument must be const(actually const and avaolable at compile time), so it can be infered by compiler

Comment: its one of the cases where you can think of the non-constant reference as a constant pointer (ie cannot rebind)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non type template arguments that are references can be non-const.

The reason for your error is that you are trying to bind a `const` object to a non-const reference. The error is gone if both `const` are removed:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Country {
    std::string name;
};

template<Country& country>  // no const necessary
struct S{
    void print() {
        country = Country{"foo"};
        std::cout << country.name;
    }
};

static Country sg{"sg"};    // no const

int main() {
    S<sg> sg_printer;  
    sg_printer.print();    
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rPovnW5Kr)

Comment: ah I thought C++ will not let me modify what template argument points to... although tbh I wish that was enforced, this code is insane https://godbolt.org/z/qY3hnTdYK